# Service Worker html Response not been displayed on the browser

Tags: javascript, offline, service-worker

I'm trying to respond to service worker events with an html reply, and I dont get any output on the browser. I don't understand why.Here is my code.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

event.respondWith
{
    new Response("<h1>Hello!</h1>", {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
})};    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondwith is a function. Should be invoked with parameters in parenthesis `func(params)` like this

```
event.respondWith( new Response("<h1>Hello!</h1>", {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many reasons cause this not work

- not in HTTPS, localhost or 127.0.0.1 environment
- service worker file address is not right

if you use Chrome you can use chrome://inspect/#service-workers to check your service worker